# Searching a string array without built in methods

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search, binary-search

If anyone can help out there, I'll be tremendously grateful.

Essentially I am working on a homework project where, for part of it, I need to search an array. The array, I currently have as a String type, but is essentially a collection of dates. (In the format 05/06/2014)

I am just about at my wits end trying to find a way to allow the user to search this array, in particular that doesn't use built in methods like array.binarysearch etc.

I tried to implement a binary search but that didn't seem to work, I can provide code if you wish to see where I'm probably going wrong. But is there perhaps a better search I should use for this string type, or should I be converting the string array into a different type?

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciated, I'm not necessarily asking for anyone to do my work for me I'd just be thrilled if someone could bump me in the right direction, as this problem has been doing my nut in. Thanks!

Current Binary Search Code:

```
public static void BinarySearch(string[] dateArray, string searchTerm)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = dateArray.Length - 1;
    int position = -1;
    bool found = false;
    int compCount = 0;


    while (found != true && first <= last)
    {
        int middle = (first + last) / 2;

        int comparisonSTR = string.Compare(dateArray[middle], searchTerm);

        if (dateArray[middle] == searchTerm)
        {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
            compCount++;

            Console.WriteLine("Your search has been found after " + compCount + "comparisons.");
        }

        else if (comparisonSTR > 0)
        {
            last = middle;
            compCount++;
        }

        else
        {
            first = middle;
            compCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would definitely be a good idea to post your code, especially the code you think is incorrect.  It is difficult to provide guidance if we don't really know what you are doing/trying to do.

Comment: The code would be helpful to tell you what is going wrong with your binary search. It may also be better to use DateTimes for that kind of data. It's a much easier comparison.

Comment: If you are comparing dates don't compare them as strings, but as `DateTime` instances. The "cannot use built in methods" remark reeks of homework. Which is fine, but be upfront about it.

Comment: Added the code I had for my binary search that doesn't seem to work.

Apologies if I didn't seem upfront about that, have now amended

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting what you are trying to do. Is the `dateArray` input argument to `BinarySearch` sorted?

Comment: It is indeed sorted in descending order, the the 0th element in the most recent date

Comment: Well, then make sure that (1) instead of using strings you convert them to `DateTime` instances, using their specific date format, and (2) you find and fix the bugs in your binary search. You should be all set.

Comment: Will get right onto that, thanks ever so much man!

Comment: To add to nice  @Alex's comment - with dates it would really help if you look at http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 0):

For an educational response, your binary search is correct*, if not very clean - like @Alex said, you only have to make sure you're comparing them as DateTimes. The problem is with the line

```
int comparisonSTR = string.Compare(dateArray[middle], searchTerm);
```

because the "string class" doesn't know what a date is so it can't really give you a datetime comparison when you're trying to search for dates. It can only give you a comparison on if one term comes alphabetically before, equal, or after another term.

Instead, if you convert them to DateTimes and use the comparer specific for DateTimes, then you should get back a comparison that you can use for binary search. You can either convert them to DateTime in-line

```
int comparisonSTR = DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(searchTerm), Convert.ToDateTime(dateArray[middle]));
```

or convert them outside of the loop as the first thing you do in your method to make it a little easier to read

```
DateTime[] dates = Array.ConvertAll(dateArray, Convert.ToDateTime);
DateTime searchDate = Convert.ToDateTime(searchTerm);

while (found != true && first <= last)
{
     int middle = (first + last) / 2;
     int comparison = DateTime.Compare(searchDate, dates[middle]);
```

Other than that, you're pretty much set. You might have already solved this by now, so in that case I'm just posting it in part to explain why the `string.Compare` didn't work for you to convert dates in this case.

Edit: Make sure to test your edge cases (e.g. searching for not only the middle, but also the first and last elements for varying array sizes), because I suspect that your binary search may not be entirely correct on second review.

Comment: You must like infinite loops.

Comment: Ah ok, I see you may have spotted the problem

Comment: Yes, I didn't go over it carefully enough. My mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not feeling very confident about my search as it appears to do absolutely nothing.

Regardless of what sort of implementation I seem to try and do it appears to return nothing to the console. I have a feeling this is gonna require some ground up work now, damn

Comment: What input are you giving it? I ran the code and it returned an answer for me. Are you keeping your console open to see the results afterward?